# prove the bound in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

For all real value function $f$ in $C^\infty_0(D)$ where $D$ is **bounded** domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$

If norm $\|f\|^2_0 = \int_Df^2dx$ and $\|f\|^2_1 = \int_D\sum f_i^2 dx$ (where $f_i$ is $\partial_if$)

Now prove the following ineuqality:

$$\|f\|_0 \le d\|f\|_1$$

where $d$ is the width of domain $D$

I have shown for each direction $i$ ,we have the following inequality:

$$f^2(x)\le d\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_i|^2dx_i$$

How to combine them togethter?(this looks quite like Sobolev inequality)

My attempt:since $\int_D f^2(x) dx \le d^2\int_D |\partial_1f|^2 dx \le d^2\int_D\sum_i|\partial_i f|^2 dx$ which is exactly the result.

Since all the function are non-negative we can use Fubini here

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

First, try to prove it when $D\subset \mathbb R$, and use the fact that since $f\in \mathcal C_0(D)$, then there is $a\in D$ s.t. $f(x)=0$, i.e. $$f(x)=\int_a^x f'(u)\,\mathrm d u.$$

Jensen inequality allow you to conclude. I let you generalize when $D\subset \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Hi I have proved the rest of $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is my proof correct? Quite direct correct?Not even need to know the information of the rest of coordinate.

Comment: I still don't know why it's Jensen inequality?

Comment: @yi_li: I don't understand your proof (the first equality is wrong). In the case of $\mathbb R$, you need Jensen to pass from $f(x)^2$ to $\int f'(u)^2du$.

Comment: Hi,here:   $|f(x)|^2 = |\int_a^x f'(u) du|^2 \le (\int_a^x |f'(u)| du)^2  \le (x-a) \int_a^x |f(u)|^2 du$    What's wrong with this inequality?The last inequality due to Schwaz inequality

Comment: You forgot the $\int_a^x (f')^2$ at the RHS. Notice that Cauchy-Schwartz and Jensen inequality are the same here ;-) @yi_li

Comment: Yeah thank you that's true since we use Jensen inequality to prove the Holder inequality

Comment: @yi_li: not at all !

Comment: What do you mean by that ?

Comment: @yi_li: you don't use Jensen to prove Holder (and you don't use Holder to prove Jensen)